# Proving $Y\setminus\{(-1,0)\}$ using the standar topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing

> Consider $Y$ to be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $Y=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}\cup\{(x,y):(x-2)^2+y^2=1\} $.
>
> I want to prove that $Y\setminus\{(-1,0)\}$ is connected.

I thought of using discs in $\mathbb{R}^2$,but I am not allowed to use the concept of distance.

I try to go by contradiction by admitting that there is a clopen set in the subspace $Y\setminus{(-1,0)}$ but that lead me nowhere.

**Question**:

How should I prove $Y\setminus{(-1,0)}$ is connected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(-1,0)$ is only on one of the circles so you essentially have a figure eight with a point missing. There is only one point that can be removed to disconnect $Y$.

Comment: @JohnDouma I know that. The point to disconnect Y is (1,0)(that is the reason I removed (-1,0)). But I am looking to write a proof that $Y\setminus\{(-1,0)\}$ is connected.

Comment: Try using path-connectedness. If you can find a continuous curve from between any two points, then the set must be connected.

Comment: @TheoBendit I meant to try to use only connectedness.

Answer (score 1):

$\{(x,y)
:x^{2}+y^{2}=1\}\setminus (-1,0)$ is connected and so is $\{(x,y)
:(x-2)^{2}+y^{2}=1\}\setminus(-1,0)$. Since the point $(1,0)$ is common to these, their union is connected.